# Configuration Error

Tags: npsp

How do I correct a configuration error in the **NPSP Sandbox**, trying to **Upload**, that appears to be wrong?

> Error: The Contact Custom Unique ID setting field External_ID__c must
>   have matching fields in the NPSP Data Import object whose API Names
>   are Contact1_External_ID__c and Contact2_External_ID__c.

I checked under Contact and only the first API name is on the list. The **Contact2 External ID** is not appearing. How do I correct this? thanks!

Comment: Check the data import object not the contact

Comment: It matches the Contact as well. Both with 18 characters and Number fields. The API is 'External_ID__c' not 'Contact2_External_ID__c'